# Funcionalidad con imágenes en vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Ando buscando como hacer lo mismo que hace esta página https://www.norstedts.se/ en el apartado "Nytt & kommande". Una serie de imágenes que cuando clicas en ellas te muestra otro contenedor con información desplazando las demás filas para que el nuevo div entre en su sitio sin tapar nada y cuando vuelvas a clicar vuelva todo al origen.
Me está trayendo por el camino de la amargura intentar implementar la función y os voy a poner el código que tengo (seguro lleno de errores) a ver si alguien pudiera guiarme. Muchas gracias de antebrazo.

```
// Crea dinámicamente el contenedor de libros en JavaScript
const listBooks = document.querySelector('.listBooks');
let selectedBook = null;
let detailsOpen = false;
let bookDetailsContainer = null;

// Función para mostrar los detalles del libro al hacer clic en la imagen
function showBookDetails(book, bookElement) {
    console.log('showbookdetails');
    console.log('Clic en la imagen del libro:', book);

    if (detailsOpen && selectedBook && selectedBook.key === book.key) {
        // Si los detalles están abiertos y se hace clic en el mismo libro, oculta y elimina los detalles
        hideAndRemoveBookDetails();
    } else {
        // Si los detalles están cerrados o se hace clic en un libro diferente, muestra los detalles
        selectedBook = book;
        displayBookDetails(bookElement);
        detailsOpen = true;

        // Ajusta la altura de listBooks para evitar overflow
        adjustListBooksHeight(bookElement);
    }
}

// Función para ajustar la altura de listBooks
function adjustListBooksHeight(bookElement) {
    const row = bookElement.parentElement; // Obtén la fila actual
    const totalRowsHeight = row.clientHeight; // Altura de la fila actual

    // Desplaza el contenedor de detalles hacia arriba si está fuera de la vista
    const listBooksRect = listBooks.getBoundingClientRect();
    const detailsRect = bookDetailsContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (detailsRect.bottom > listBooksRect.bottom) {
        const adjustment = detailsRect.bottom - listBooksRect.bottom;
        bookDetailsContainer.style.top = `${parseFloat(bookDetailsContainer.style.top) - adjustment}px`;
    }
}

// Función para ocultar y eliminar los detalles del libro
function hideAndRemoveBookDetails() {
    if (bookDetailsContainer) {
        bookDetailsContainer.remove(); // Eliminar el contenedor
        selectedBook = null;
        detailsOpen = false;
    }
}

// Función para mostrar los detalles del libro
function displayBookDetails(bookElement) {
    console.log('displaybookdetails');

    // Crea el contenedor de detalles
    bookDetailsContainer = document.createElement('div');
    bookDetailsContainer.classList.add('bookDetailsContainer');
    listBooks.appendChild(bookDetailsContainer);

    // Limpia el contenido del contenedor
    bookDetailsContainer.innerHTML = '';

    if (selectedBook) {
        const titleElement = document.createElement('h2');
        titleElement.textContent = selectedBook.title;

        const authorElement = document.createElement('p');
        authorElement.textContent = `Author: ${selectedBook.author_name ? selectedBook.author_name.join(', ') : 'N/A'}`;

        const coverImage = document.createElement('img');
        coverImage.src = `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/${selectedBook.cover_i}-L.jpg`;
        coverImage.alt = selectedBook.title;

        bookDetailsContainer.appendChild(titleElement);
        bookDetailsContainer.appendChild(authorElement);
        bookDetailsContainer.appendChild(coverImage);

        const rect = bookElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const rowRect = bookElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Ajusta la posición del contenedor debajo del libro clicado
        bookDetailsContainer.style.top = `${rect.bottom - rowRect.top}px`;
        bookDetailsContainer.style.left = `${rect.left - rowRect.left}px`;

        // Desplaza las filas siguientes solo si la fila actual es la primera
        if (rowRect.top === listBooks.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
            const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
            let totalTranslateY = 0;

            rows.forEach((row) => {
                // Ajusta el desplazamiento solo si la fila está debajo del nuevo div
                if (rowRect.bottom > totalTranslateY) {
                    const adjustment = bookDetailsContainer.clientHeight;
                    row.style.transform = `translateY(${adjustment}px)`;
                }

                totalTranslateY += row.clientHeight;
            });
        }

        adjustListBooksHeight(bookElement);
    } else {
        hideAndRemoveBookDetails();
    }
}

// Función para cargar los libros
function loadBooksInfo() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=bestseller&limit=18';

    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Error de red: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            const spanishBooks = data.docs.filter(book => book.language && book.language.includes('spa'));
            displayBooks(spanishBooks);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error al cargar libros:', error);
        });
}

// Función para mostrar los libros en el contenedor
function displayBooks(books) {
    // Limpiar el contenido de listBooks
    listBooks.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if (i % 6 === 0) {
            const row = document.createElement('div');
            row.classList.add('row');
            listBooks.appendChild(row);
        }

        const book = books[i];

        const coverImage = document.createElement('img');
        coverImage.src = `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/${book.cover_i}-L.jpg`;
        coverImage.alt = book.title;

        const bookElement = document.createElement('div');
        bookElement.classList.add('book', 'hoverable');
        bookElement.appendChild(coverImage);

        bookElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            showBookDetails(book, bookElement);
        });

        const currentRow = listBooks.lastElementChild;
        currentRow.appendChild(bookElement);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    loadBooksInfo();
});
introducir el código aquí
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mil disculpas pero para responderte no consideraré tu código, te responderé como lo haría yo.

Digamos que tenemos una grilla de elementos (las portadas de las fotos), para eso usaría CSS grid, porque permite hacerlo responsivo de manera automatica.

Luego queremos que al presionar un `cuadro` (la portada) , se añada un elemento  `detalle` justo debajo de la fila del cuadro clickeado, para eso hay que:

- Determinar index del cuadro, es decir tengo 10 cuadros, del 0 al 9 ¿Cual es su index?. Para esto se usa `indexOf`. A este valor le llamaré `selected`
- Luego necesitamos saber cuantas columnas tiene la grilla, porque supongo debe ser responsivo, y por ende la cantidad de columnas es variable. Para esto usamos `getComputedStyle` para obtener los valores calculados del CSS del elemento. A este valor le llamaré `gridColumnCount`
- Y por ultimo necesitamos calcular el index del último elemento de fila clickeada, para añadir un nuevo elemento después de este. Para esto usamos los valores anteriores. Siendo:

```
ultimo = gridColumnCount - selected%gridColumnCount -1 + selected;
```

Demo: Ahí te explico más detalles,

```js
function Mostrar(){
  
  const detalle = grilla.querySelector(".detalle");
  
  //lista de todos los cuadros
  const cuadros = Array.from(grilla.querySelectorAll(".cuadros"));
  
  //index del cuadro clickeado
  const selected = cuadros.indexOf(event.target);
  
  //si el cuadro detalle existe, pero es el mismo que he vuelto a clickar
  if(detalle && detalle.dataset.id == selected){
    detalle.remove(); //lo removemos
    return; //y paramos la ejecución
  }
  else if(detalle){ //si cuadro detalle existe, pero hemos clickado otro
    detalle.remove(); //solo lo removemos
  }

  const gridComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(grilla);  
  
  //cantidad de columnas
  const gridColumnCount = gridComputedStyle.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length;
  
  //el ultimo de la fila  
  let ultimo = gridColumnCount - selected%gridColumnCount -1 +selected;

   //si el ultimo supera la cantidad de elementos, será simplemente el mayor de la lista
  if(ultimo >= cuadros.length){
    ultimo = cuadros.length-1;
   }

  //añadimos el elemento luego del ultimo de la fila
   cuadros[ultimo].insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<div class='detalle' data-id='${selected}'></div>`);

}
```

```css
#grilla{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
 gap:10px;
}

.cuadros{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:160px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.detalle{
background-color:red;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height:160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grilla">
 <script>
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      document.write("<div class='cuadros' onclick='Mostrar()'></div>");
    }
 </script>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, es justo lo que necesitaba. Un saludo!